# MeshLab Rendering STL solids by name

Tags: meshlab

I have an STL file that MeshLab renders well.

[image]

The STL file contains multiple named solids. ( It represents items packed into bins.) The file looks like this:

```
solid VBA330K005
facet normal 0.000000e+000 0.000000e+000 -1.000000e+000
outer loop
vertex 0 0 0
vertex 347 0 0
vertex 0 219 0
endloop
endfacet
....
endsolid VBA330K005
solid VBA330K009
...
```

I need to be able to visualize the individual solids by name. Highlight a particular solid, or hide it.
I have searched around on the GUI, but cannot see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The use of multiple '`solid`' in a single STL file is not quite common and MeshLab does not support it.

You can try to issue a feature request on github. If many will support it eventually it will be implemented.

In the meantime probably the easiest thing is just to split your file using awk

```
gawk ' /solid/ { ++a; fn=sprintf("item%02d.stl", a); 
    print "Writing: ", fn } { print $0 >> fn; } ' mycomposedstl.stl
```